# WP Ajax removes shortcodes from the post in non-authenticated mode

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I have a strange issue with a custom wordpress theme.

I have enabled AJAX actions in my theme as following:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_get_levelOne_Content', 'get_levelOne_Content');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_levelOne_Content', 'get_levelOne_Content');
```

`get_levelOneContent` does not do anything fancy. Rather it simply fetches the post content and return the HTML output as the AJAX's payload.

```
function get_levelOne_Content()
{   
    $postid = $_POST["postid"];
    
    require(get_template_directory() .'/../../../wp-load.php');
    @header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=' . get_option('blog_charset'));
    @header('X-Robots-Tag: noindex');
    send_nosniff_header();
    nocache_headers();
    
    $post_content = get_post($postid);
    print_r($post_content);
    $content = $post_content->post_content;
    $title = $post_content->post_title;
    $currentLang = apply_filters('wpml_current_language', null);    
    ?>
<div class="wrapper__content fw fx fx__row">
    <div class="post__content fx fx__col p__4">

        <h2 class="txt0-t"><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
        <div class="m__t-2">
            <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $content);?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
exit();
} ?>
```

The post that I am interested in has a WP Form shortcode tag. This code works perfectly fine, and as intended when I am logged in as a user in this site.
However, as a non-authenticated user, the shortcode does not appear in the payload through get_post() method. I verified this with `print_r($post_content);`, which does not show anything related to the shortcode present in the original post.

I have used my known skills to fix this issue, but I am unable to do so. Before posting here, I have searched around the internet and tried out various solutions, but none of the suggested solutions worked.

Can anyone please suggest me something?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try any other shortcode other than WP Form?

Comment: hi ! yes, I just tried with the embed tag, and it worked as intended. so, the problem lies in WPForms Configuration?

Comment: Yes, because you are already using the correct hooks (one for logged in and one for not-logged-in uses). Maybe your WP Forms is configured to be displayed only for logged-in users. You can try to use `Contact Form 7` or `Formidable Forms`  to create the same form.

Comment: thanks. my problem is that I am "almost" forced to use WPForms at the moment. I tried to see settings related to visibility in WP Forms, but could not find anything relevant.

Comment: Please see this link. https://wpforms.com/how-to-restrict-access-to-logged-in-users-on-your-wordpress-forms/ It is a documentation for restricting access. So you can check these settings and see whether you accidentally restricted your form or not.

Comment: thanks for the link. I had tried this earlier as well. I also enabled other addons and played around with some settings. It appears to me that I am not able to embed the form's shortcode and view it anonymously. So, the issue is not related to WP Rest API at all. Rather, the culprit is WPForms in total. I will try few things now and I will post back later. Thank you for your inputs.

Comment: Good luck then!

Comment: narrowing down this issue, I came to a point that when I invoke `wp_head()`, then it filters out WPForms shortcode in non-authenticated mode. By any chance do you have any idea of such a thing?

Comment: I have no idea why it would happen.

Comment: i have even more confusing stuffs now. If I try to retrieve the post via single.php file as `while(have_posts()): the_post; echo the_content();....` etc, then the form gets rendered correctly regardless of authentication. However, if I try to retrieve the same post via wp_Query or get_posts, the WPForms magically gets disappeared in non-authenticated mode.